# Почему происходит конфликт?

Tags: jquery

Привет всем. Подскажите в чем проблема? Есть скрипт, который работает на jquery 1.4 - 1.5. Я хочу изменить библиотеку на 1.11 или немного ниже, но 1н select перестает корректно работать. Сама идея в том, что при клике на селект происходит выборка значений(цена, метро) и отображается результат на карте + внизу списком. На версии 1.4-1.5 все нормально работает.

```
jsfiddle.net/wms3dgam/2/
```

Хочу использовать галерею 1.11, а не получается из-за того, что селект не работает один(тот, который с чекбоксами), а второй работает.

Comment: Пример, представленный вами по ссылке не рабочий. Есть обращение к отсутствующим функциям и переменным.

Comment: вставил весь код. Некоторые селекты не вставлял в код на фиддл. Иначе не могу показать((